# Randomly taking a string and putting it into a Stack?

Tags: java

I currently have an ArrayList with 52 elements. Each it a different card from a deck. I am trying to randomly pull a "card" from ArrayList and put it into a stack but am having some trouble. How would I use Random rand = new Random(); to pull a string indicating a card and store it in a stack?

Comment: Collections.shuffle()

Comment: Do you need to pull out only one card, or several cards?

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Items> items = ...
Collections.shuffle(items);
```

Now just take the items off the list in order.  They will be randomized from the shuffle.

You can also pass your own instance of `Random` as a second argument to shuffle. That is primarily useful when specifying a seed.  Then it will always shuffle the same way.  It's good for testing.

---

A different approach is to create a wrapper class for a `List` to return the values randomly.  It makes a defensive copy of the list to avoid permuting the supplied list and guarantees that no value will be repeated.  And like `Collections.shuffle()` you can supply an instance of `Random` as the second argument.

```
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
        RandomList<Integer> rlist = new RandomList<>(list);
        rlist.forEach(a->System.out.print(a + " "));
```

This instance printed

```
3 1 5 10 7 8 4 6 2 9
```

```
class RandomList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private int count;
    private List<T> list;
    private Random r;

    public RandomList(List<T> list) {
        // make a defensive copy of passed list.
        this(list, new Random());
    }

    public RandomList(List<T> list, Random rand) {
       this.list = new ArrayList<T>(list);
       this.r = rand;
       count = list.size();
    }
    private class MyIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return count > 0;
        }

        public T next() {
            // get a random index
            int i = r.nextInt(count--);
            // and retrieve that value
            T v = list.get(i);
            // that value is now "used"
            // so replace it with the last
            // value in the list.
            list.set(i, list.get(count));
            return v;
        }
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, an `ArrayList` is *not* a front-end for an array, it is a **`List`** that happens to be implemented using an array internally, same as `LinkedList` is a `List` that is implemented using a doubly-linked chain of nodes. If they had decided to name it e.g. `StdList`, it would still be a `List` implemented using an array internally, but you wouldn't think of it as a front-end for array. The name just reflects the implementation, is all. --- As for my "criticism" being without foundation, I'd point out that I was not criticizing, but making a humorous observation, hence the "LOL" and "".

Answer (score 0):

@WJS has suggested a solution but if you want to use `Random` then you can use

To pull a random string from ArrayList, find a random index and get the element and put it into stack and remove that element from the arraylist

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int index=rand.nextInt(list.size());
String card=list.get(index);
stack.push(card);
list.remove(index);
```

Comment: But if you want to explicitly use `Random`, specify it on the `shuffle` call: `Collections.shuffle(items, new Random())`

Answer (score 0):

If you use rand.nextInt(52);
It randomly draws a value between 0 and 51 (both included).

How can you get the 1st or nth or 52th card from your data ?

Comment: 0 **is** the 1st card and 51 **is** the 52nd card.

Comment: yes but I was just trying to guide the OP without giving the answer away^^

Comment: @GuillaumeB Sounds like something you should then have said in a comment, not an answer.